# Double Integral $\int_{0}^{4a}\int_{y^2/4a}^{y}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$ to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{4a}\int_{y^2/4a}^{y}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\  \mathrm dx\ \mathrm dy$$

I wanted to solve this double integral using polar coordinates but unfortunately, I am not able to get the right limits. Please help

**My Try:**

The integral gets reduced to somehow
$$\large \int_{?}^{?}\int_{0 ?}^{4a ?}r\cos2\theta\ \mathrm  dr\ \mathrm d\theta $$

Can someone explain this via graph ? I am not sure why 90 degrees upper limit

Comment: That is not the nicest domain to do polar coordinates with...You have a lune between $\;y=x\;$ from below and $\;2\sqrt{ax}\;$ from above ( assuming $\;a>0\;$) - changing the integration's order) . That won't be nice to deal with polar coor...In fact, the azimut angle is very nice: $\;\pi/4 \le \theta\le \pi/2\;$ , but the length coordinate $\;r\;$ ...hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

We should write restrictions for set on $xy$ plane in polar coordinates, which gives

$$\begin{cases}0 \leqslant r\sin\alpha \leqslant 4a \\
\frac{r^2\sin^2 \alpha}{4a}  \leqslant r \cos \alpha \leqslant r\sin\alpha
\end{cases}$$
So, additionally to being in first quadrant, we obtain $\tan \alpha \geqslant 1$, from right side of second line, i.e. $\alpha \geqslant \frac{\pi}{4}$, and $r \leqslant \frac{4a \cos \alpha}{\sin^2 \alpha}$ from left side. For integral we have
$$\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{4a \cos \alpha}{\sin^2 \alpha}}$$

Comment: You got it correct. But explain theta a little bit... Pi/2 how ??

Comment: We have $0 \leqslant \sin \alpha$ from first line and  $0 \leqslant \cos \alpha$ from second. Both together gives $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: from second line $cos \alpha \ge rsin^2\alpha/4a$ not 0

Comment: @Aman Rajput. When $a > 0$, then  $\frac{r^2\sin^2 \alpha}{4a}  \leqslant r \cos \alpha $ gives $0 \leqslant \cos \alpha$. No?

Comment: a is real no where mentioned it is greater than 0

Comment: In my answer it is clearly written in the first line of system. Implicitly this follows from the writing the integral, when we mean the left boundary less than the right one. Anyway, suppose you insist that, $a < 0$, then this is the case when the figure on the plane will be in the 3rd quadrant and not in the first. The boundaries reversed in both the first and second integrals. This figure is symmetric about the center of the plane and since the integrand is also symmetric, then, the answer will be equal to the considered case.

Comment: Thanks I understood,